# Java RMI buffered image not serializable

Tags: java, serialization, rmi, bufferedimage

currently I'm tring to use RMI to transmit buffered image data. As far as I known, buffered image is not serializable, so I write a wrap class to try transmitting it.

```
public class SrlzImg implements Serializable {
    private BufferedImage img;

    public BufferedImage getImage(){
        return image;
    }

    @Serial
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", buffer);
        out.writeInt(buffer.size());
        buffer.writeTo(out);
    }

    @Serial
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        int size = in.readInt();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        in.readFully(buffer);
        this.image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
    }
}
```

and here is how I transmit it in remoteImplementation

```
public class RemoteImplementation extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteInterface {
    private SrlzImg img = new SrlzImg(new BufferImage(...));
    ... 
    @Override
    public SrlzImg getImg() throws RemoteException {
        return img;
    }
}
```

and this is how client gets the image

```
BufferedImage img = remoteInterface.getImg().getImage();
```

Currently I cannot find what's wrong with this but I get `NotSerializableException` when client tries to get the buffered image using the code above. Can any see whats happening here?

Comment: Should you not make your `img` instance variable `transient` for this to work?

Comment: You need to get and set the byte array from the `BufferedImage`. Writing a serializable wrapper class with a non-serializable member doesn't change anything useful.

Comment: @user207421 So what if I extend ```BufferedImage``` and implements Serializable? Does that change this situation?

Comment: @AhSoHard Just make the member `transient`. Subclassing `BufferedImage` and implementing `Serializable` would only work if you also made all its fields serializable. Hint: It's not serializable for a reason. 

Comment: @ Harald K Thank you, that somehow works. Java does not throw me exception. But another issue is that, if client tries to get the serializable buffered image (```SrlzImg```), they will get the (```SrlzImg```) instance, but with empty ```BufferedImage``` member. But it should be at least not null as ```SrlzImg``` is initialized with ```new SrlzImg(new BufferImage(...))```. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: @AhSoHard That won't work either, as you could have discovered by experiment all by yourself. For the same reason.